# Javascript / Jquery: Show and hide a Loading Screen message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the following behavior to happen.

1) User clicks on a link on my site

2) I show text which says the next page is loading

3) Then the user goes to the next page.

4) If the user clicks Back to go to the original page, the text which says loading is no longer there.

I don't know how to implement #4.  I've tried window.onbeforeunload but couldn't get it to work properly.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>My website</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="loadingDiv" style="display:none;">
        This should show when I click on link. This should not show when users leaves this page and then clicks back.  
    </div> 

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('.button').click(function() {
            $('#loadingDiv').show();
        });        
    });
    </script>

    <br><br>
    <a class="button" href="http://www.google.com">Open google</a>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There are many people who feel that vanity loading or simulated loading animations are bad. I personally don't care, but for you to accomplish what you want is going to require quite a bit of code. i can provide you some pointers but ultimately you're on your own.

Comment: On back button click, `$('#loadingDiv').show();`?

Comment: The reason I am doing this is my site is relying on 3rd party APIs.  It takes very long to load the next page and I don't want the user to keep clicking buttons thinking nothing is happening.  In addition, I am required to keep the user from submitting their info more than once to the partner so I need to disable all buttons while the next page is loading.

Comment: well thats easy. `$('.button').click(function(){ $(this).disabled(1).val('Working...');$('#loadingDiv').show(); $('title').html('Processing please wait');alert('Please wait while we process your request');$('body').css('background-color','#333333','opacity','0.4');});` your options are limitless here.

Comment: The problem is when the user goes to the next page, if they click back, all of these changes are retained.  E.g., I don't want bgcolor to be #333333 ... I want the page to appear the same as it would if user refreshed the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's radically different from what you have attempted, but with some modifications, you could have similar functionality to what I have achieved with this. It adds some nice little AJAX animations while changing pages;, triggering a dark but opaque overlay div and a loading div each with fixed positioning.

**the jquery**

```
$('a.animate').click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href'),
    toLoad = href+' #main-content';
    $('#overlay').show();
    $('#loader').show();
    $('#page-content').hide();
    $('#main-content').load(toLoad,'', function(){
        $('#main-content').show('fast',function(){
            $('#loadingDiv').hide('slow',function(){
                $('#overlay').hide();
            });
        });
    });
    window.location = href;
    return false;
});
```

**the html**

```
<div id="loader" class="bubblingG">
<img src="your-ajax-img" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"/>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>

<div id="main-content">
    <div id="page-content">
    <!-- your page content goes here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

**the css**

```
#loader {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -31.5px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    height: 63px;
    width: 100px;
    display: none;
}
#overlay{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 995;
    top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;
    background: #333;
    opacity: 0.4;
    display: none;
}
```

**NOTE** You can't nest `#loader` within `#overlay` or it will inherit the opacity from `#overlay`. This is a known problem with CSS, so you have to position it by itself with z-index and normal positioning methods to prevent opacity in your `#loader` div.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the loader with delay:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
  // show just 2 sec
  $('#loadingDiv').show().delay(2000).hide();
});
```

Comment: The loading div must stay there until the user has left the page. It is a modal dialog which doesn't allow the user to click any other buttons.